# How can we interpret biplot?

Tags: clustering, pca

This is not a question as such but more likely to be verification (enhancement) of my current understanding. With the thought that it may help future visitors as well, I am taking liberty to make this post.

[image]

**Question**

- Is the interpretation mentioned in attached image correct ?
- As per my interpretation, Movie A doesn't seems to have much Action, nor Drama. What does that mean? Is it boring movie or what?
- I would like to give some intuitive name to PC0 and PC1, what seems to be suitable name for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In short, Answer to your questions:*

- Yes
- Movie A is near to center of the plot. Its the most balanced movie from your collection. (Biplot's center reflects the average of PCA scores: neither positive nor negative).
- *PC1* scores are positively correlated with with Romantic/ Comedy  and negatively with Action movies. *PC0* is mostly negatively correlated with Drama movies.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. It did helped. Would it reasonable to say that PC1 represent "soft" movies, for PC0 - i am not sure about how to name anti-dramatic movies...

Comment: That would be one of the right interpretations for it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a movie that balances action, drama, comedy, and romance.

Where would it likely be in this chart?

Comment: I wish if you can elaborate on this.